# Does copying a database in PostgreSQL preserve statistics?

Tags: postgresql

When using CREATE DATABASE  TEMPLATE  in PostgreSQL, will the target database preserve the statistics from the source database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a straight file-level copy of the template database, so whatever was in there will be in the new database.

Comment: Hmm, I cloned a database that had a vacuum/autovacuum listed in pg_stat_user_tables for example, but the cloned database did not (using "create database new template old;"). It seems the statistics did not get copied, I wrong?

Comment: The pg_stat_* tables are not actually tables but views that access information in shared memory.  So the information there is not affected by the copying of the template database.

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe so -- You will get a copy of the tables/triggers/etc., but they will have new OIDs, and the statistics will need to be regenerated.

It's possible that the statistics will be populated for you (equivalent of doing an `ANALYZE` on the new DB) - I haven't investigated that though, and if it's not the case you can speed up the process by doing it manually.

Comment: At least initially, the tables and such will have the same oid / relfilenode in both the new and old database.